# CORS in embedded javascript

Tags: javascript, cors

I'm intending to add security for our Javascript code which gets embedded on other sites - eg: like analytics code.

The user copies 4-5 lines of the code and puts it on his site. The code actually downloads the real script as the next step.

I have been recommended to use CORS instead of the current JSONP calls as I can restrict the domains.

As I understand, the CORS would work only if the html page which will add my scripts needs to add access domains and if I add the access domains for the the js file, it wouldn't work.

Is the CORS for the final js or the html page intending to use my script?

Edit:

Since it's confusing to the users, I have made it more simple.

HTML in domain A adds my script from Domain B like Google analytics. Can I add access-domains: while rendering my JS or should the HTML add the access-domains in the response?

Answer (score 0):

[CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) works by having your server output the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) header containing the allowed domains. The sites that make ajax requests to your server don't need to do anything special to enable CORS, there is no configuration required. The sites just simply make normal XHR requests and the browser will internally handle the CORS.

You control the CORS access from the header on your server. In CORS, you can also control the HTTP verbs that are allowed, for example POST or GET (`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`) or the permitted request headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`).

Note that IE8 doesn't support the CORS XHR, Microsoft decided to create their own CORS implementation with [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). So if any of the sites that call your server want to support IE8, they will need to use [XDomainRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of XMLHttpRequest. There is no support for CORS in IE7 or eariler - not even XDomainRequest.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good explanation from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#CORS_relationship_to_JSONP) for this question:

`CORS` can be used as a modern alternative to the `JSONP` pattern. While `JSONP` supports only the `GET` request method, `CORS` also supports other types of `HTTP` requests. Using `CORS` enables a web programmer to use regular `XMLHttpRequest`, which supports better error handling than `JSONP`. On the other hand, `JSONP` works on legacy browsers which predate CORS support. `CORS` is supported by most modern web browsers. Also, while `JSONP` can cause cross-site scripting (`XSS`) issues where the external site is compromised, `CORS` allows websites to manually parse responses to ensure security.

> As I understand, the CORS would work only if the html page which will add my scripts needs to add access domains

You can access all domains via:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Also now `CORS` has [good support](http://caniuse.com/cors).

P.S. IE8-9 has own imlementation by `XDomainRequest`.